# Uncaught ReferenceError: loadNext is not defined (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, function

I am getting this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: loadNext is not defined
(anonymous function)
```

The line that is causing this is

```
<img name="imageLoad" class="hiddenPic" src="<?php echo "albums/$folder/$startImage"; ?>" onLoad="javascript:loadNext();" />
```

It refers to this function above the image tag.

```
function loadNext() {
    ///alert("maxphoto="+maxPhoto+"start="+start+"loadingindex"+loadingIndex);
    loadingIndex = nextPhotoToLoad(1, maxPhoto,start, loadingIndex);
    if (loadingIndex != '')
    {
        document.images['imageLoad'].src = img[loadingIndex-1];
    }
}
```

The function is defined. Why am I getting a an error where it says it is not defined?

**Edit**: Here is the entire file. http://pastebin.com/gu1V5RMd

Comment: You should not put `javascript:` before the function call, but that should not be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassing. It wasn't inside head tags.

Comment: </script>
<img name="imageLoad" class="hiddenPic" src="<?php echo "albums/$folder/$startImage"; ?>" onload="loadNext()" />
 
</head> check lines 141-145

Comment: ? The image should **not** be inside the head. It should be where you want it to appear in the document.

Answer (score 0):

try `onload="loadNext()"` instead of `onLoad="javascript:loadNext();`

P.S.: Make sure your function definition is surrounded by script tag.

Comment: Nope. That doesn't change anything.

Comment: I didn't see the PS. It is surrounded in script tags. I was talking aobut the onload part.

Comment: obviously, you misplaced the whole tag!!<img name="imageLoad" class="hiddenPic" src="<?php echo "albums/$folder/$startImage"; ?>" onload="loadNext()" /> you put in head tag. It should be inside of body! i hope this helps!

Comment: Woops. That still does not fix the problem.